# Rundeck: Schedule from from Sunday Morning until Friday Afternoon

Tags: cron, rundeck

I have a Rundeck job that I would like to schedule to run from Sunday at 10 am to Friday at 17:00.

I could create three separate instances of the job and schedule it as below:

```
#every Sunday starting at 10 until midnight
0 */15 10-23 ? * 1

# every fifteen minutes starting on Monday midnight to Thursday 11:59 am
0 */15 * ? * 2-5 *

#every Friday starting at 12 am until 17:00 pm
0 */15 00-17 ? * 6
```

But it seems like there has to be a better way that will allow me to do this in one job. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is with Calendars feature (Enterprise), you can assign each rule to a single job. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/schedules/project-schedules.html#project-schedules-enterprise).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. Unfortunately we don't have the enterprise versions.